# Physical meaning of third derivative with respect to position

Tags: differentiation, non-linear-systems, dispersion, integrable-systems

I currently on a numerical solver for the KdV equation which reads

$$ u_t + uu_x = u_{xxx} $$

I was wondering the physical sense of this third derivative with respect to $x$. I know that the $uu_x$ term is a convection term and that a second and fourth derivative modelize diffusion but I have no idea about the third derivative.

I used my Fourier spectral code to solve it in order to understand and I obtained the following profile after one second of simulation :

[image]

Looks like the third derivative has the same effect has the convective term.

Comment: Equation $u_t + \alpha u_{xxx} = 0$ is linear. The dynamics can be understood by using the dispersion relation of this equation. To see a role of $u_{xxx}$ numerically, it is better to consider a pulse-like initial condition (not sine-wave). I suspect that $u_{xxx}$ results in a dispersive decay of the pulse, and its asymmetry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Korteweg-de Vries equation is a nonlinear dispersive wave equation which describes the amplitude of shallow water waves. The version of the equation you're quoting is the nondimensionalized and rescaled version. According to this [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Korteweg-deVriesEquation.html) from [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/) the original equation reads

$$ \frac{\partial\eta}{\partial{t}}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt\frac{g}{h}\left(\eta\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial{x}}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{\partial\eta}{\partial{}x}+\frac{1}{3}\sigma\frac{\partial^3\eta}{\partial{}x^3}\right)$$

As specified in the comments, the meaning of the third derivative is specific to the problem. Have a look at [this derivation](http://lcd-www.colorado.edu/~axbr9098/teach/ASTR_5410/material/KdVDeriv.pdf) of the equation by Professor Axel Brandenburg from the University of Colorado if you want to understand the details of the equation.

To put it simply the third derivative is responsible for the dispersivity of the equation. If you add a scalar prefactor to this derivative you will observe a dispersion of your initial cosine wave. I found the following animation on the [Wikepedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korteweg%E2%80%93de_Vries_equation) of the equation. It's the numerical solution of $u_t+uu_x+\delta^2u_{xxx}=$ with $\delta=0.022$ and an initial condition $u(x,0)=\cos\pi{}x$.

[image: Dispersion in the KdV equation]

If you want to run the simulation by yourself you can use the Python code below. This code is an adaptation of the MATLAB code from [Llyod N. Trefehen](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/spectral.html) (`p27.m`). It uses Fourier spectral method with an integrating prefactor and the Runge-Kutta scheme. A simple Fourier spectral code with the Euler implicit method will do the work too.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def animate(i,uu,line):
    line.set_data(x,uu[100*i,:])
    return line,

a  = .022 # dispersion prefactor
N  = 256
tf = 2.
dt = .001
Nt = int(round(tf/dt))
x0 = -np.pi
xf =  np.pi
x  = (xf-x0)/N*np.arange(-N/2,N/2)
u  = np.cos(x) # initial condition
uu = np.zeros((Nt,N)); uu[0,:] = u

M = int(round(N/2))
k = np.zeros(N)
k[0:M] = np.arange(0,M); k[M+1:] = np.arange(-M+1,0,1)
ik3 = 1j*k**3
U = np.fft.fft(u) # go to spectral space
for n in range(1,Nt):
    t = n*dt
    g = -0.5j*dt*k
    expaik = np.exp(a*dt*ik3/2) # integrating
    expaik2 = expaik**2               # factor
    # Runge-Kutta scheme
    rk1 = g * np.fft.fft(np.real(np.fft.ifft(U))**2)
    rk2 = g * np.fft.fft(np.real(np.fft.ifft(expaik*(U+rk1/2)))**2)
    rk3 = g * np.fft.fft(np.real(np.fft.ifft(expaik*U+rk2/2))**2)
    rk4 = g * np.fft.fft(np.real(np.fft.ifft(expaik2*U+expaik*rk3))**2)
    U = expaik2*U + (expaik2*rk1 + 2*expaik*(rk2+rk3) + rk4)/6
    u = np.real(np.fft.ifft(U)) # back to real space
    uu[n,:] = u

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.gca()
line, = ax.plot([],[])
ax.plot(x,uu[0,:])
ax.legend(['current time','initial'])
ax.set_xlim(x0,xf)
ax.set_ylim(-1,3)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$u(x)$')
ax.grid(True)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=int(Nt/100),fargs=(uu,line),repeat=False)
anim.save('anim.mp4')
plt.show()
```

[image: Simulation animation]

Comment: Just to refine a point -- for any convection-type problem, odd derivatives are dispersive and even are diffusive. Depending on the leading coefficients, they might be anti-dispersive or anti-diffusive, respectively. But odd ordered derivatives are always related to dispersion and even are always related to dissipation.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailled anwser. However, I'm having a little trouble understanding how the scheme work...

Comment: Have a look at this [anwser](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144508/how-to-solve-a-4th-order-pde-using-fourier-spectral-method/3522595#3522595) I wrote about this scheme

Comment: @tpg2114 this seems to go against the answer as you suggest the behaviour is not tied to the specific problem but somewhat generic to third derivatives.  Would you have a reference to this as I’m rather interested in learning more on this issue?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Not sure that it conflicts per se -- this is a convection-type equation, and my statement is true for all convection-type equations. The KdV is essentially an inviscid Burgers equation with a dispersion term. I'll see if I can find references, but my knowledge of dispersion vs. dissipation is rooted in numerical method analysis via modified equations. For example, [this presentation](https://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~kuzmin/cfdintro/lecture10.pdf).

Comment: My statement may be true for all equations. But I don't know that for sure and don't want to take that leap. Of course, what dispersion of a variable means does depend on the specific equation... so again, not sure there is a conflict.

Comment: @tpg2114 thanks for the link.  I will have a look for sure.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Numerical analysis is my jam, so if there's something you want to talk about, you can ping me in chat.

Comment: @tpg2114 I promise to do this although it might not be in the near future.

Comment: @tpg2114 I remembered this bit of conversation and I'd like to come back to this in the near future.  If you have a bit of time towards the end of the month I'll ping you in chat.